# Invalid default value for column/variable (ed_fec_sol)

Tags: default, informix

I'm trying to compile this procedure in Informix Data Base, but the result is:

> Invalid default value for column/variable (ed_fec_sol).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE admfte.cds93_val_deu_sol ( ec_tip_deu CHAR(02),
                                 ec_ind_ori_com CHAR,
                                 ec_num_ruc LIKE sol_comp.num_ruc_des,
                                 ec_num_val LIKE sol_comp.num_doc_des,
                                 ec_per_tri LIKE sol_comp.per_tri_des,
                                 ec_sem_doc LIKE sol_comp.sem_doc_des,
                                 ec_cod_tri LIKE sol_comp.cod_tri_des,
                                 ec_cod_dep CHAR(4),
                                 ed_fec_sol  DATE DEFAULT '01/01/0001' )
RETURNING SMALLINT, CHAR(250), CHAR(8), SMALLINT, CHAR(17),
      CHAR(6), CHAR(6), CHAR(6), CHAR(6), CHAR, DATE, DATE;
{*************************************************************************}
DEFINE ls_cod_for     LIKE crt.crt_formul;
DEFINE lc_num_doc     LIKE dbt.dbt_numdoc;
DEFINE lc_cod_tri     LIKE valores.cod_tri;
DEFINE lc_cod_tri_aso LIKE valores.cod_tri_aso;
DEFINE lc_cod_tip_doc LIKE valores.cod_tip_doc;
DEFINE lc_not_abo     CHAR(8);
DEFINE ld_fec_ori     DATE;
DEFINE ld_fec_pre     DATE;
DEFINE lc_per_doc     CHAR(6);
DEFINE lc_sem_doc     CHAR; 
DEFINE ls_cod_err     SMALLINT;
DEFINE lc_msg_err     CHAR(250);
DEFINE li_count       INTEGER;
DEFINE lc_num_exp_fra LIKE pre_op_fra.num_doc;

DEFINE GLOBAL gc_CodUsu CHAR(08) DEFAULT USER;DEFINE GLOBAL gc_FlgDeb CHAR(01) DEFAULT '0';DEFINE lc_file_log CHAR(100); DEFINE lc_flg_debug CHAR(1); DEFINE lc_flg_explain CHAR(1); DEFINE lc_MsgDebIni VARCHAR(60); DEFINE lc_MsgDebFin VARCHAR(60);
SET OPTIMIZATION LOW;
IF gc_FlgDeb = '1' THEN SELECT flg_debug, flg_explain INTO lc_flg_debug, lc_flg_explain FROM pbdebugspl WHERE usuario = USER AND nom_spl = "cds93_val_deu_sol"; IF lc_flg_debug = "1" THEN LET lc_file_log = "/tmp/" || USER || "_" || "cds93_val_deu_sol" || ".log"; LET lc_MsgDebIni = "Iniciando   ===> " || "cds93_val_deu_sol"; LET lc_MsgDebFin = "Finalizando ===> " || "cds93_val_deu_sol"; SET DEBUG FILE TO lc_file_log; TRACE ON; TRACE lc_MsgDebIni; END IF; IF lc_flg_explain = "1" THEN SET EXPLAIN ON; END IF; ELSE LET lc_flg_debug = '0'; END IF;

LET lc_not_abo = "0";
LET ld_fec_ori = '01/01/0001';
LET lc_per_doc = ec_per_tri;
LET lc_sem_doc = ec_sem_doc;
LET lc_cod_tri = ec_cod_tri;
LET lc_cod_tri_aso = "0";
LET lc_cod_tip_doc = "0";

IF ec_tip_deu = "02" THEN   -- DDJJ

CALL cds93_ver_hay_ops (ec_num_ruc, ec_per_tri, ec_sem_doc, ec_cod_tri)
  RETURNING ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err;

IF ls_cod_err > 0 THEN   -- ls cod_err contiene la cantidad de OPs
  RETURN -24, lc_msg_err, "0", 0, "0", "0", "0", "0", 
         '000101', '0', 
         '01/01/0001', '01/01/0001';
END IF

CALL cds91_existe_deb (ec_num_ruc, ec_per_tri, ec_sem_doc, ec_cod_tri, ec_cod_dep)
    RETURNING ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, lc_not_abo,ls_cod_for,lc_num_doc,ld_fec_pre;

IF ls_cod_err = 1 THEN
  CALL cds91_fecha_deb (ec_num_ruc, ec_per_tri, ec_sem_doc, 
                        ec_cod_tri, ec_cod_dep, ed_fec_sol)
       RETURNING ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, lc_not_abo, ls_cod_for,
                 lc_num_doc, ld_fec_ori, ld_fec_pre;

  LET lc_per_doc = ec_per_tri;
  LET lc_sem_doc = ec_sem_doc;
  LET lc_cod_tri = ec_cod_tri;
  LET lc_cod_tri_aso = '0';
  LET lc_cod_tip_doc = '0';
--[2008-000422] : INICIO. SAU20082I020401360]
ELSE
  RETURN ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, "0", 0, "0", "0", "0", "0", '000101',
         '0', '01/01/0001', '01/01/0001';
END IF
--[2008-000422] : FIN. SAU20082I020401360]
ELIF ec_tip_deu = "01" THEN -- VALOR

CALL cds93_obt_dat_val (ec_num_val, ec_num_ruc, ec_ind_ori_com)
    RETURNING ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, lc_cod_tri, lc_cod_tri_aso,
              lc_cod_tip_doc, lc_per_doc, lc_sem_doc, ld_fec_ori, ld_fec_pre; 

IF ls_cod_err < 0 THEN
  RETURN ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, "0", 0, "0", "0", "0", "0", '000101',
         '0', '01/01/0001', '01/01/0001';
END IF

LET ls_cod_for = 0;
LET lc_num_doc = ec_num_val;

{PAS20082A510000808 : INICIO}
IF lc_cod_tip_doc = '001004' OR
  lc_cod_tip_doc = '001005' OR
  lc_cod_tip_doc = '001007' OR
  lc_cod_tip_doc = '017004' OR
  lc_cod_tip_doc = '017504' OR
  lc_cod_tip_doc = '017604' THEN

  IF (lc_cod_tip_doc = '001004' OR
      lc_cod_tip_doc = '001005' OR
      lc_cod_tip_doc = '001007') THEN

     SELECT MAX(num_doc)
       INTO lc_num_exp_fra
       FROM pre_op_fra
      WHERE pre_op_fra.num_val = ec_num_val
        AND ind_est_op = '2'
        AND ind_gen_op = '3';

     IF lc_num_exp_fra IS NOT NULL AND 
        LENGTH(lc_num_exp_fra) > 0 THEN

        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO li_count
          FROM pre_op_fra, valores
         WHERE pre_op_fra.num_val = valores.num_val
           AND pre_op_fra.num_doc = lc_num_exp_fra
           AND ind_est_op = '2'
           AND ind_gen_op IN ( '1', 
                               '2' ) 
           AND ind_sal = '1';

        IF li_count = 0 THEN
           RETURN ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, lc_not_abo, ls_cod_for, lc_num_doc, lc_cod_tri,
                  lc_cod_tri_aso, lc_cod_tip_doc, lc_per_doc, lc_sem_doc, ld_fec_ori,
                  ld_fec_pre;
        END IF
     END IF
  ELSE
     RETURN ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, lc_not_abo, ls_cod_for, lc_num_doc, lc_cod_tri,
            lc_cod_tri_aso, lc_cod_tip_doc, lc_per_doc, lc_sem_doc, ld_fec_ori,
            ld_fec_pre;
  END IF
END IF
{PAS20082A510000808 : FIN}
END IF

{** Existe restriccion para la compensacion a determiandos tributos **}
CALL cds93_val_tributo(lc_cod_tri, 1)
 RETURNING ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err;
IF ls_cod_err < 1 THEN
RETURN ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, "0", 0, "0", "0", "0", "0", '000101',
      '0', '01/01/0001', '01/01/0001';
END IF 

RETURN ls_cod_err, lc_msg_err, lc_not_abo, ls_cod_for, lc_num_doc, lc_cod_tri, 
   lc_cod_tri_aso, lc_cod_tip_doc, lc_per_doc, lc_sem_doc, ld_fec_ori, 
   ld_fec_pre;
END PROCEDURE
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What value do you use for the `DBDATE` environment variable?  I use `DBDATE=Y4MD-` so that dates are in the same (ISO 8601) format as `DATETIME YEAR TO DAY`, and I was able to get `create procedure def_date(d date default '0001-01-01') returning date;
return d + 365;
end procedure;` to work correctly. If you use either `DBDATE=MDY4/` or `DBDATE=DMY4/`, then your default `'01/01/0001'` should work equivalently. I tried various alternatives: `DEFAULT MDY(1,1,1)` and `DATE('0001-01-01')` and `DATETIME(0001-01-01) YEAR TO DAY` and they all gave errors. Locale-dependent date strings are a nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan mentioned, the key to your problem is the [DBDATE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_212.htm?lang=en) environment variable, although other environment variables can be used ([GL_DATE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_079.htm?lang=en), [CLIENT_LOCALE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_065.htm?lang=en)) this one takes precedent.

You can check if you have any of this set by querying the [sysenvses](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0227.htm?lang=en) [SMI](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0210.htm?lang=en) table:

```
SELECT      envses_name, envses_value
FROM        sysmaster:sysenvses
WHERE       envses_name IN (
                            'DBDATE', 
                            'GL_DATE', 
                            'CLIENT_LOCALE'
                            )
            AND envses_sid = DBINFO('sessionid')
ORDER BY    DECODE(envses_name,
                'DBDATE',           0,
                'GL_DATE',          1,
                'CLIENT_LOCALE',    2
            );
```

This will get you by the order of [precedence](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1832.htm?lang=en).

If you have not set any of this you should check if `DBDATE` is set on the server side by querying [sysenv](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0226.htm?lang=en):

```
SELECT  env_name, env_value
FROM    sysmaster:sysenv
WHERE   env_name = 'DBDATE';
```

If in doubt you can just check how dates are dealt by:

```
SELECT  CURRENT::DATE
FROM    sysmaster:sysdual;
```